# Java - Binary Tree pointer still null after initialization?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

This question is very abstract and thus very hard to describe or search for, thus why I am here. It's a very simple question however.

I have the following class:

```
class Node<T>
{
    Comparable data;
    Node<T> left, right;

    public Node(Comparable data)
    {
        this.data = data;   
    }
}
```

What happens if I have:

```
/*
* Imagine this root looks like the following:
*       10 (root)
*       /       \
    null        null
*/
Node root;

// Imagine we are inside of the insert method and this
// is the current value that is going to be inserted.
int valueIAmTryingToInsert = 5;

// As we see from the tree above, "child" WILL be null.
Node child = (valueIAmTryingToInsert.compareTo(root.data) < 0 ? root.left : root.right);

if (child == null)
{
    child = new Node(data);
    return true;    
}

// Recursive statement would happen here.
```

Notice that child is a pointer that points to either the left or the right child of `root`. BUT, what happens if I instantiate the Node that `child` is pointing to? After calling `child = new Node(data);`, does the tree currently look like:

```
    10 (root)
    /       \
    5       null
```

If It **doesn't** look like that, explain why. Because my understanding is even though `Node child` is null, the pointer is *still* pointing to one of `root`'s children. I am pretty sure this doesn't work, as my editor underlines `child` in the statement `child = new Node(data);` and claims `The value new Node(data) assigned to 'child' is never used` (even though it is being used).

Comment: Here's actually a much simpler way to describe my question. Why does [THIS](http://i.imgur.com/glhuKeX.png) yield a null pointer exception? second points to first, which is initially null, but then becomes an initialized object and thus should point to it properly.

Comment: root node has yet been initalised? So root.data will throw NPE. Also, you created a child Node but has yet attached to the root node?

Comment: As per your comment, when you call "new" you are creating a NEW reference in memory for the object. Null is no reference. That's why, second and first point to null, but then when you instantiate first, second is still pointing to null, and then second.x throws the NPE

Comment: @MinhKieu I didn't want to write out an entire fully fledged tree so just pretend that `root` is initialized and has many children, etc.

Comment: @aquiros But `second` is pointing to to the variable `first`. This should mean that no matter what happens to `first`, it should remember where `first` is in memory. Are you saying that when I call `first = new ...` it actually changes memory locations and is no longer where it once was?

Comment: Second is not pointing to first. Second is pointing to null (nothing) and also first is pointing to null. Then when you call first = new..., it assign a memory allocation to first, but only to first; if not, then every freaking object declared pointing to null will point to the new memory reference. Null is like void, no reference in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never assigning it to the root node as its "left".

In plain English this is what your code does:

-Is the left (or right) of the root null?
-Yes
-Create a new node please.

But there's no association between this new Node and the root Node.
You might need something like this:

```
Node root;
Node child;
Integer valueIAmTryingToInsert = 5;
if(valueIAmTryingToInsert.compareTo(root.data) < 0){
    if(root.left == null){
        root.left = new Node(valueIAmTryingToInsert);
    }
    child = root.left;
}else{
    if(root.right == null){
        root.right = new Node(valueIAmTryingToInsert);
    }
    child = root.right;
}
return true;
```

EDIT:
This code is just an example, but if `root.data` is null you'll get a `NullPointerException` because of the comparision. That's something you might be aware and take care of.

EDIT 2:
I can see you're still confused and the main issue is that you have to keep in mind that `null` is not a reference to an object. It is a "mark" that indicates that the object has not been yet initialized. So when I say `a = null; b = a` is not like `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object (Because `null`is not a valid object or reference), it means they both have not yet been initialized. They are separate independent variables. Then when I initialize one `a = new MyClass()` I'm asking for a memory reference for `a`, but b remains pointing to nowhere in memory.

See `null` as a way of telling "This object is pointing to nowhere". 
If things were as you are thinking (If I initialize `a` then `b` should point there too); then every single null object in the program should point to where `a` is now pointing to.

Comment: @Hatefiend This would be a adequate solution for the problem. If you still want to use a tenary operator, it is still possible to assign child to root.left or root.right after you created it in your final if-conditional

Comment: See, I'm trying to avoid having nested if statements though. I SORT of understand your initial explanation, but not really. I just don't understand. `root.left` is pointing to `child` (in this situation). I then change `child`, and yet `root.left` still thinks `child` is null. It makes no sense.

Comment: Regarding your edit, my actual code is much more detailed than this so don't worry I've taken care of any null problems. This is the only hold up.

Comment: @Hatefiend Where do you say root.left is pointing to child (in this situation)?

Comment: Wait wait... I got myself confused. Sorry -- my main misunderstanding is in my OP, why is `child` still null. That's what just makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Hatefiend you mean `root.left`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that `child = new Node()` will change what object your pointer points to, not any values of the object the pointer pointed to before and definitely not what object other pointers point to (like `root.left`).

`root.left` and `child` are NOT the same variable, even after calling `child = root.left`! They only point to the same object. So changing what one points to does not influence the other.

Basically, `new Node()` creates a new object somewhere in your memory. `child = new Node()` does the same thing, except afterwards it tells the variable child to point to that newly created object instead of whatever it pointed to before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. > root.left and child are NOT the same variable < This is what I don't understand. `root.left` is pointing to a `Node`, and I say `Node child`, point to the same node that `root.left` is pointing to. How can they not be pointing to the same `Node`?

Comment: They are. It's just that once you say child = whatever you make child point to a different node instead.

Comment: Imagine telling one person to look at a blue car. Then tell a second person to look at whatever the first person is looking it. Afterwards you create a new, red car and tell the second person to look at it. What is the first person looking at now?